# Why can't I use an alias for an aggregate in a having clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My code is like shown below :

```
select col1,count(col2) as col7
from --some join operation
group by col1
having col7 >= 3 -- replace col7 by count(col2) to make the code work
```

My code causes the error "Invalid column name 'col7' ". Why does this happen ? It seems illogical that SQL does not allow me to use col7 in the last line.

I am using SQL server express 2008

Comment: Because logically, the SELECT column list and aliases happen *after* the HAVING clause

Comment: What DBMS are you using because I think that is totally valid in MySQL.

Comment: @AndreKR - sql server express 2008

Comment: It's funny to me that people are offering answers that are even more verbose than just doing it the normal way.  I think the point here was to simplify the code, not just to be able to use an alias for the sake of using an alias.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In MS SQL, the only place (I'm aware of) that you can reference aliases is in the ORDER BY clause.  The ability to reference aliases in other parts of the query is a feature that many other db platforms have and honestly it annoys me that Microsoft hasn't considered it a useful enough feature to add it.

Comment: so how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Instead of trying to reference the alias, you could force the count() to run first by nesting it in another query. This way you can reference it from the original select, where, or have. See my answer for details.

Comment: Pretty sure PostgreSQL also doesn't let you put aliases in HAVING clauses.

Comment: You can also use aliases in the GROUP BY clause (at least in Postgres).

Answer (score 81):

The `HAVING` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` - so the server doesn't yet know about that alias.

1. First, the product of all tables in the `FROM` clause is formed.
2. The `WHERE` clause is then evaluated to eliminate rows that do not satisfy the search_condition.
3. Next, the rows are grouped using the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.
4. Then, groups that do not satisfy the `search_condition` in the `HAVING` clause are eliminated.
5. Next, the expressions in the `SELECT` statement target list are evaluated.
6. If the `DISTINCT` keyword in present in the select clause, duplicate rows are now eliminated.
7. The `UNION` is taken after each sub-select is evaluated.
8. Finally, the resulting rows are sorted according to the columns specified in the `ORDER BY` clause.
9. `TOP` clause is executed.

Hope this answers your question. Also, it explains why the alias works in `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Meanwhile in Postgres you can use aliases in `GROUP BY` and still can't in `HAVING`... Here your theory completely crashes.

Comment: What's more you miss one important point. All parts of the query are parsed before it's executed. So technically, nothing prevents us from using select aliases in other clauses.

Comment: Sorry but no, your theory is wrong. As Mike stated – you can use alias in GROUP BY. Why one can't use aliases in HAVING clause?

Comment: Does this order still hold when using common table expressions or does the order then apply to each sub-CTE separately?

Answer (score 11):

You should select twice to use the count() column

```
select * from (select col1,count(col2) as col7
from --some join operation
group by col1) as temp
where temp.col7 >= 3
```

Comment: Of all the solutions here, this just seems the best/easiest way.

Comment: This solution is not optimal (depending on the DB) because the inner query is returning more results than the original query would have.

Answer (score 8):

Try with this one as the select list contains the same expression you can use in having clause also:

```
SELECT COL1,COUNT(COL2) AS COL7
FROM --SOME JOIN OPERATION
GROUP BY COL1
HAVING COUNT(COL2) >= 3
```

Comment: This can potentially be awfully expensive if the aggregating function is compute heavy

Answer (score 4):

In SQL the execution flow of clause is,
From --> where --> group by --> having --> select --> order by --> distinct --> top.

Since alias where declared in select clause so it is not available for clauses which is executed before select ( it's available for clauses which are executing only after select )
But there is another way to use alias,  by using nested select
Eg: select * from (select name, salary, salary+1000 as hike from employee ) as emp where hike > 10000;

Answer (score 1):

U can use this code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') is not null DROP TABLE #temp

-- Create tempurary table
CREATE TABLE #temp (Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1), col1 BIGINT, countOfcol2 BIGIN)

--insert from the table 2 #temp
INSERT INTO #temp (col1,countOfcol2) 

select col1,count(col2) as col7
from --some join operation

select col1,countOfcol2 from #temp
group by col1
having countOfcol2 >= 3 -- replace col7 by count(col2) to make the code work
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using a nested query.

I have also run into this problem when I am wanting to improve performance. I have needed to run a `count()` based on certain fields within a JSON field in a table, obviously we would want to parse JSON only once instead of having to include a separate count in a `where` or `have` clause (especially an expensive one like in my case).

If `col1` is a unique id, the most computationally efficient way could be to nest the count in a separate `select`

```
select col1, innerquery.col7
from whatevertable
inner join (select col1, count(col2) as col7 
            from whatevertable 
            group by col1) as innerquery 
            on innerquery.col1 = whatevertable.col1
where innerquery.col7 >= 3;
```

This way the count is only ran once, creating a sort of temporary lookup table for reference by the rest of your query.

Again, this only works if `col1` is unique for every record, which normally isn't too much to ask since most tables have some sort of id primary key.

Answer (score 0):

select col1,count(col2) as col7
from --some join operation
group by col1
having **count(col2)** >= 3;

Honestly I am miffed as to why SQL Server does not process the column alias. I use this as a workaround. It still prints the column name as your alias but processes using the original aggregate function.

Comment: I have done this too. When you still get results in a timely manner this is fine, but I also posted a solution that only has to run the count() once, just in case anyone has more intense logic inside of their count().