# MS SQL Server and invalid column name even though it is an alias

Tags: php, sql-server

I work with PHP and MS SQL Server OBDC Connect. I will make a Near Me search but I get the error:

```
DATABASE QUERY ERROR [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'distance'.
```

But Distance is an alias? Why do I get the error? Without WHERE it works fine.

```
$sql_nearme = "SELECT place.place_logo, place.place_rank, place.percent_points, place.points, place.place_id, place.place_adress, place.place_description, place.place_photo, place.place_name,(6371 * acos(cos(radians(".$map['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].")) * cos(
                      radians(place.place_lat)
                  ) * cos(
                      radians(place.place_long) - radians(".$map['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'].")
                  ) + sin(
                      radians(".$map['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].")
                  ) * sin(
                      radians(place.place_lat)
                  )
              )
          ) AS distance
  FROM place WHERE distance < 100 ORDER BY distance ASC OFFSET ".$blatt_start." ROWS FETCH NEXT ".$blatt_end." ROWS ONLY";
```

Comment: You can't use an alias in your WHERE clause

Comment: Can i use HAVING with a alias in mssql?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14049515/575376

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use aliases in the where clause. You can either use the case statement in the where clause, or turn your query into a subquery without the where clause in which case that alias is now a column name which you can check against in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put into subquery or use the whole condition in where clause as below:

```
$sql_nearme = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT place.place_logo, place.place_rank, place.percent_points, place.points, place.place_id, place.place_adress, place.place_description, place.place_photo, place.place_name,(6371 * acos(cos(radians(".$map['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].")) * cos(
                      radians(place.place_lat)
                  ) * cos(
                      radians(place.place_long) - radians(".$map['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'].")
                  ) + sin(
                      radians(".$map['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].")
                  ) * sin(
                      radians(place.place_lat)
                  )
              )
          ) AS distance
  FROM place ) A WHERE A.distance < 100 ORDER BY A.distance ASC OFFSET ".$blatt_start." ROWS FETCH NEXT ".$blatt_end." ROWS ONLY";
```