# Firebird column unknown on SELECT AS

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table of calls and their durations:

```
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| ID | CALLER_NUMBER | CALLEE_NUMBER | CALL_DURATION |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|  0 | 1xxx0001020   | 1xxx3024414   |          0.30 |
|  1 | 1xxx1002030   | 1xxx0303240   |        134.24 |
|  2 | 1xxx2003040   | 1xxx0324220   |        330.00 |
|  3 | 1xxx3004050   | 1xxx5829420   |        104.00 |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I want to select all numbers that called for over 500 seconds in total. My query uses `SELECT AS` to rename the `SUM(...)` field so I can reference it in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT CALLER_NUMBER, SUM(CALL_DURATION) AS TOTAL
FROM CALLS
GROUP BY CALLER_NUMBER
HAVING TOTAL > 500
```

When I run this query in Firebird SQL, I get the following error:

```
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed

SQL Message : -206
can't format message 13:794 -- message file not found

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -206
Column unknown
TOTAL
At line 4, column 8
```

Comment: You need to repeat the sum expression in the `HAVING`

Comment: @HoneyBadger Will this re-select the sum for every row to find out if it needs to be included?

Comment: @user7401478 most probably not. And if it would - it would do so regardless of sing alias or not. However why asking? you can just easily check it! Make a `selectable stored procedure` and let it count how many time it was called (easiest thing to do - just pulling from some `generator` in SP and then returning zero).

Comment: Related (for SQL Server, but the explanation applies): [Why can't I use an alias for an aggregate in a having clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048672/why-cant-i-use-an-alias-for-an-aggregate-in-a-having-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the `alias` in the `having` clause.

You should use `sum` in the `having` clause as follows:

```
SELECT CALLER_NUMBER, SUM(CALL_DURATION) AS TOTAL
FROM CALLS
GROUP BY CALLER_NUMBER
HAVING SUM(CALL_DURATION) > 500
```